# jQuery wave animation on row of icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a row of icons on my page and i want to create a wave animation effect when user hovers over them with the cursor.

I'm using this basic code for starters:

```
$('#icons > li')
    .hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'top': (-1 * hover_distance)
        }, hover_speed);
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'top': 0
        }, hover_speed);
    })
;
```

And it looks OK. But there is one issue: when you move your cursor frantically over the icons, the animation queue for every icon is becoming filled with lots of actions (up, down, up, down, up, down, etc) and icons is going up and down lots of times even if you stop to interact with the icons.

I want my icons to complete only one cycle (up and down) and then stop the animation. I'm looking for a most elegant (short, simple, light) solution for this.

PS: And you can't just use *stop()* because it will prevent the "wave effect" (i.e. when you move your cursor with one fast stroke over the icons and they move up and down in response, like a real wave).

PPS: Here's the JS-Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nZqLy/3/

Comment: You could apply the `hover` event on a parent element which is not moving and then animate its children.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.stop()` before the animations to stop the current animation or `.stop(true)` to cancel all animations in the queue. http://jsfiddle.net/nZqLy/9/

```
$('#icons > li').hover(function() {
  $(this).stop(true).animate({
    'top': (-1 * hover_distance)
  }, hover_speed);
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({
    'top': 0
  }, hover_speed);
});
```

Comment: It will destroy the "wave effect". See my P/S please.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something? Would help to find a solution.

Comment: I've added JSFiddle to a question. See my PPS.

Comment: what you keep referring to as the "wave effect" is the queueing of the animation ... it allows the full animation to complete. Unfortunately, queueing is a boolean, so either you allow it (creating the wave effect, but the many cycles possibility remains), or you prevent it (no wave effect). There is no method to "only queue once".

Comment: @PlantTheIdea if there is no high-level solution, it doesn't mean it can't be done. Maybe we can interact with the animation queue directly to achieve this.

Comment: @SlavaFominII Just use the `stop(true)` on the first animation. Will prevent the queuing of multiple animations but keeps the wave effect. Probably the best you will get: http://jsfiddle.net/nZqLy/2/

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 Oh, thank you. I should have seen this. Could you please update your post to this: http://jsfiddle.net/nZqLy/4/ so it will contain most updated solution. And i will accept it )

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted the answer by @jimjimmy1995, but just to provide an alternative way of doing the same animation which will be faster and more efficient:

```
$('#icons').on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({top:(-1*hover_distance)},hover_speed);
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({top:0},hover_speed);
    }
},'li');
```

The only differences are:

1. The use of `.on()` is more transparent, but also allows for more extensibility (you can add more on events later, like `mousemove` or something, if you want)
2. Delegation of all `li` from `#icons` rather than making `#icons > li` the selector means the animation binding is only applied once, rather than many times (one time for each `li`) - this is the most important of the three changes
3. Using the native DOM name rather than the string (`top` vs `'top'`) is a best practice. It makes no difference for non-hyphenated words, but when you start dealing with `marginTop` vs `'margin-top'` it makes a difference.

**UPDATE**

Found the solution:

```
$('#icons').on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':animated')){
            $(this).animate({top:(-1*hover_distance)},hover_speed);
        }
    },
    mouseleave:function(){
        $(this).animate({top:0},hover_speed);
    }
},'li');
```

Using the [:animated selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) checks if the item is in progress of being animated. The if logic will only perform the animation if it is not.

[jsFiddle to prove it](http://jsfiddle.net/nZqLy/8/).

Comment: Thank you for the event delegation idea - it's a good optimization.

Comment: Updated my solution to include the :animated selector, which I believe does exactly what you want.

Comment: Didn't think of doing it that way. +1

Comment: realized i didnt need the if logic on the `mouseleave` event, updated it.